# sort a dictionary by values and by key tuple python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I want to know how to organize the dictionary by the key that is a tuple:
first order by the first number, then the second letter and then the third number.

Also, I want to know how to organized first by values (first value 1, then value 2 and then value 3):

INPUT:

```
d= {
 (2,x,50): 
    {
        'val1': 2, 
        'val2': x,
        'val3': 50,
        'val4': 'hu',
        'val5': 'ho',   
    }
 (1,a,30): 
   {
       'val1': 1, 
       'val2': a,
       'val3': 30,
       'val4': 'hey',
       'val5': 'hi',   

    }, 
  (2,x,20): 
    {
        'val1': 2, 
        'val2': x,
        'val3': 20,
        'val4': 'hu',
        'val5': 'ho',   
    }
(2,b,10): 
    {
        'val1': 2, 
        'val2': b,
        'val3': 10,
        'val4': 'hu',
        'val5': 'ho',   
    }
 }
```

OUTPUT:

```
 d= {
(1,a,30): 
   {
       'val1': 1, 
       'val2': a,
       'val3': 30,
       'val4': 'hey',
       'val5': 'hi',   

    }, 
 (2,b,10): 
    {
        'val1': 2, 
        'val2': b,
        'val3': 10,
        'val4': 'hu',
        'val5': 'ho',   
    }
(2,x,20): 
    {
        'val1': 2, 
        'val2': x,
        'val3': 20,
        'val4': 'hu',
        'val5': 'ho',   
    }
 (2,x,50): 
    {
        'val1': 2, 
        'val2': x,
        'val3': 50,
        'val4': 'hu',
        'val5': 'ho',   
    }
  }
```

I have tried ordering by key:

```
   sorted(d, key = operator.itemgetter(1))
```

and have tried ordering by value, but I get an error:

```
   sorted(d, key = operator.itemgetter('val1', 'val2', 'val3'))
```

Comment: What error do you get? Just mentioning it without specifics is not useful.

Comment: the value passed to `key` *will be the keys* of a dictionary. You could do `operator.itemgetter(1,2,3)` but it's not neessary, tuples are already ordered lexicographically

Answer (score 1):

You can try to sort the dictionary items this will sort the dictionary according to the keys then dictionary comprehension can be used to parse the sorted result as a dictionary.

```
d= {
 (2,'x',50):
    {
        'val1': 2, 
        'val2': 'x',
        'val3': 50,
        'val4': 'hu',
        'val5': 'ho',   
    },
 (1,'a',30):
   {
       'val1': 1, 
       'val2': 'a',
       'val3': 30,
       'val4': 'hey',
       'val5': 'hi',   

    }, 
  (2,'x',20):
    {
        'val1': 2, 
        'val2': 'x',
        'val3': 20,
        'val4': 'hu',
        'val5': 'ho',   
    },
(2,'b',10):
    {
        'val1': 2, 
        'val2': 'b',
        'val3': 10,
        'val4': 'hu',
        'val5': 'ho',   
    }
 }
print({i[0]: i[1] for i in sorted(d.items())})
```

Output

```
        {
 (1, 'a', 30): {'val1': 1, 'val2': 'a', 'val3': 30, 'val4': 'hey', 'val5': 'hi'}, 
 (2, 'b', 10): {'val1': 2, 'val2': 'b', 'val3': 10, 'val4': 'hu', 'val5': 'ho'},
 (2, 'x', 20): {'val1': 2, 'val2': 'x', 'val3': 20, 'val4': 'hu', 'val5': 'ho'},
 (2, 'x', 50): {'val1': 2, 'val2': 'x', 'val3': 50, 'val4': 'hu', 'val5': 'ho'}
}
```

Comment: This has a potential problem, in that the dictionary will be ordered by the *items* which could be different than the order of the keys. This may or may not matter, since being ordered by the items entails being ordered by the keys first, then by the values, but that tie-breaking behavior may or may not be wanted

Comment: So It will be better to sort only by the keys? About the order, it will be better to use it in a list but the PO asks the answer to be a dict.

Comment: I'm not saying it is better or worse, just that it is *different* and that difference may or may not be relevant.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be just:

```
dict(sorted(d.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Order of insertion of keys are maintained in the dictionary since python 3.7**

```
dictionary = {
    (2, "x", 50): {"val1": 2, "val2": "x", "val3": 50, "val4": "hu", "val5": "ho",},
    (1, "a", 30): {"val1": 1, "val2": "a", "val3": 30, "val4": "hey", "val5": "hi",},
    (2, "x", 20): {"val1": 2, "val2": "x", "val3": 20, "val4": "hu", "val5": "ho",},
    (2, "b", 10): {"val1": 2, "val2": "b", "val3": 10, "val4": "hu", "val5": "ho",},
}

sorted_dictionary = {key: dictionary[key] for key in sorted(dictionary)}

print(sorted_dictionary)
```

### Output:

```
{
    (1, "a", 30): {"val1": 1, "val2": "a", "val3": 30, "val4": "hey", "val5": "hi"},
    (2, "b", 10): {"val1": 2, "val2": "b", "val3": 10, "val4": "hu", "val5": "ho"},
    (2, "x", 20): {"val1": 2, "val2": "x", "val3": 20, "val4": "hu", "val5": "ho"},
    (2, "x", 50): {"val1": 2, "val2": "x", "val3": 50, "val4": "hu", "val5": "ho"},
}
```